# Sending HTML page in email via PHP

Tags: php, html, css, email

I want to send a HTML page in email with pictures and CSS stylesheet using PHP. How can I add my images and my css stylesheet witout uploading the images in a server?

Below is the PHP code for sendind the email :

```
<?php
$to = "my.account@gmail.com";

// subject
$subject = "Test mail";

// message
$message = file_get_contents("index.html"); // index.html contains images and css stylesheet which are not displayin in the email

// from
$from = "my.account@gmail.com";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= "From:" . $from;

// Mail it
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is really going to work you want. Most email clients will not display the email as you want.

Comment: How can you reference a image if  it's not on server ? Image must be on server.

Comment: Use absolute path for images & you will need to put inline styles as applying CSS won't be supported in email.

Comment: I presume you mean then you want to send as attachments? Don't. Your emails will get picked up by every spam filter ever made.

Comment: I'm using Relative Paths and for this moment I can't use Absolute Paths, yes I was thinking to attached the images..

Comment: You must upload images somewhere, the images can't be loaded in email from your localhost.

Comment: I solved the problem of the images but Do I have to inline every CSS styling? It seems highly inefficient method..

Answer (score 0):

For complex emailing you should use a Mailer class like the wonderful [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) class.

With this class it is very easy to send complex mails (like HTML mails). You find examples in the examples folder of PHPMailer.

Comment: OP is asking for Image referencing, not how to post HTML emails.

Comment: 'I want to send a HTML page' - sounds like he wants to send an HTML email with pictures in it. PHPMailer is a very good way to do this.

Comment: "How can I add my images and my css stylesheet witout uploading the images in a server?"

Comment: Because I'm using Relative Paths and for this moment I can't use Absolute Paths

Answer (score 0):

You can add send html file like this:

```
    $file_name = basename($file); // Get file name
$data = file_get_contents($file); // Read file contents 
$file_contents = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); // Encode file data into base64
$uid = md5(time()); // Create unique boundary from timestamps 
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "From: {$from_name}<{$mail_from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: {$mail_from}";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$uid}\"";
$headers[] = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.";
$headers[] = "--{$uid}";
$headers[] = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"; // Set message content type
$headers[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
$headers[] = $message; // Dump message
$headers[] = "--{$uid}";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"{$file_name}\""; // Set content type and file name
$headers[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64"; // Set file encoding base
$headers[] = "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file_name}\""; // Set file Disposition
$headers[] = $file_contents; // Dump file
// Send mail with header information
if (mail($mail_to, $subject, '', implode("\r\n", $headers) ))
    return true;
```